# Bluetooth sending data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Im new at android development. I'm developing an app where first of all, I have a main activity where I must turn On/Off the bluetooth, make it discoverable, search devices and connect to them.

After this, I go to other activity where I have a text view with a edittext and a send button, where I can write something and send it.

I've got working all the bluetooth enabling/disabling stuff, but now I need to connect to new found devices and then enter to the chat type activity and send.

I now this is pretty much work, but it would be great if you can give me an example of how can I do this. This is the code i have:

```
public class BTActivity extends Activity {

// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE_BT = 0;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Name of the connected device
public static String mConnectedDeviceName = null;

// Array adapter for device list
private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;

// Local Bluetooth adapter
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton2);
    final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton3);
    final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton4);
    final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton5);


    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            lanzarComunicacion (null);
        }
    });



    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {          
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;   
    }   




    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 

            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {


                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);           
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);   
            }

        }
    });


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //LLAMA A LA DIALOG ACTIVITY PARA VISUALIZAR LOS DISPOSITIVOS
            LanzarBusqueda(null);

        }
    });





    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { 


            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {                         
                Context context = getApplicationContext();                            
                CharSequence text = "MAKING YOUR DEVICE DISCOVERABLE";                        
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;            

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);                        
                toast.show(); 

                Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);         
                discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);

                startActivity(discoverableIntent);
            }                   
        }
    });


    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

            Context context = getApplicationContext();                        
            CharSequence text = "TURNING_OFF BLUETOOTH";                          
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;               

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, 15);                              
            toast.show();

        }
    }); 
}



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            connectDevice(data);
        }
    }
}



private void connectDevice(Intent data) {
    String address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListDialog.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    BTCommunication.mChatService.connect(device);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bt, menu);
    return true;
}


public void lanzarComunicacion (View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, BTCommunication.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void LanzarBusqueda (View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DeviceListDialog.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}